# Command line will not run MAXScript

Tags: command-line, 3dsmax

I have a command line code as follows -

```
for /r %%v in (*.max) do start %%v
```

It opens any Max file in the same folder - great.

I want it to also tell max to run any number of scripts when the file has opened, there are guides on how to do this on the 3dsMax help for eg:

-U MAXScript   = (this will open MAXScript and run a certain script on the end of a fresh 3dsmax command load.

However this does not work on the end of the initial code I need to use.
I have been researching how this could work for 2 days but keep going in circles.
Please help.

Adam

Answer (score 0):

try `for /r %%v in (*.max) do START cmd.exe /C %%v`

Comment: Thanks Alex
It opens the MAX file like the code I had and leaves the CMD window open.
But didn't help with the script running i'm afraid.

Comment: Ok, I see... Another possible option is to start 3dsmax.exe and send maxscript commands into it by UDP protocol. I have a plugin for 3ds max that serves as embedded UDP server, - it accepts strings and passes them into internal maxscript interpreter engine, and returns results back over UDP. You can explore the code here https://github.com/nmalex/remote-maxscript.dlx

Comment: .. the procedure will be: 1. compile remote-maxscript.dlx and copy it into ./plugins folder of 3ds max, 2. update Startup.ms and add ```threejsApiStart 9001 "127.0.0.1"``` so that once 3ds max is loaded, UDP server would start listening on port 9001, 3. Use test client to send maxscript commands into 3ds max: https://github.com/nmalex/remote-maxscript.dlx/blob/master/test_client/maxscript-test-client.js , you can run it with Node.js by command line ```node maxscript-test-client.js```

Comment: remote maxscript plugin no doubt works, you can see recording here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ihehi0l9PqQ

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at using 3dsmaxbatch.exe instead of 3dsmax.exe

Here is a link to the 2019 documentation:
https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/3ds-max/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2019/ENU/3DSMax-Batch/files/GUID-48A78515-C24B-4E46-AC5F-884FBCF40D59-htm.html

The command line to load a max file then execute a script should look like this

3dsmaxbatch.exe -sceneFile C:/some/path/to/maxfile.max C:/some/path/to/script.ms

Comment: Thanks Jeremy
I had looked at 3dsmaxbatch and also possibly callbacks too.
I'm new to scripting and i'm running 2018 so i'm not completely counting these out yet.
But the Script you noted in your post requires the file location if i'm not mistaken..
The issue is that the file location and file name will be different each time hence the need for a .bat that resided in the same folder and can be triggered to run any .max file within and also set the script running.
Thanks again for your response though, as I say this is all new to me..
Ad